# Ember: Set controller properties from {{ render }} helper

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple ember controller which displays a list of strings and has a search box.

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  query: undefined
  queried: (->
    this.get('model').filter (object) -> object.match(query)
  ).property('model', 'query')
```

This controller/template is only rendered within other templates.
I want to render the controller with a default query like so

```
# titles = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
{{ render 'search' titles query='abc'}}
```

The above syntax doesn't work, is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a component in this case:

```
SearchBoxComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  query: undefined
  queried: (->
    this.get('titles').filter (object) -> object.match(query)
  ).property('titles', 'query')
}});


{{search-box titles=titles query='abc'}}

// components/search-box.handlebars
{{#each item in queried}}
   {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. When should you use a component, view, or template?

Comment: In Ember guides http://emberjs.com/guides/ is a detailed description for each case.

Comment: The `{{render}}` helper does not work with bindings unfortunately so in your use case it won't accomplish what you need.  Here's a thread discussing this exact issue and the suggestion is to use a component (although components don't have controllers so that might be a problem for you) https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2545